# Any way to make Mongo filtering dynamic records faster?

Tags: mongodb

#### Scenario

I have Mongo collection `Items` that have dynamic item objects in it. Currently I have over 3 million records. I'm using C# with MongoSharp but I don't think it has anything to do with my problem.

Here is an example `Item` (**it has a lot more fields than just 3**):

```
{
  _id : "1234567890",
  Code : 888596937,
  RefNumber : "GHTZKL",
  ...
}
```

AFAIK there is no point in using TextSearch since it's not really words, just some codes so it won't give me anything beneficial. I also cannot index them all since then I will have to index every single field.

#### Problem

Right now when I filter data it takes about 1-3 seconds (on ssd). Is there any way I can make it filter my items faster or it is as fast as I can get?

Comment: This is simple: without indexes, the computer will have to scan each and every item. If there's 2GB worth of data, even if it's all in RAM already, your CPU must load, inspect and remember the result for each item which will take time. Either identify common query criteria that can be indexed and cut your candidate set by one or two orders of magnitude through an index, or use multikeys to simulate a large number of indexes, or you use a specialized search database. In any case, you must go from O(n) to O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what field you want to search on, but it sounds like you want to search on any arbitrary attribute. This is a common design and borders on an antipattern for MongoDB. The only way to avoid the collection scan you're getting now is to index the fields you want to search on, but indexing every field when you don't know what the fields will be ahead of time isn't possible. The solution to this to name only the common fields (and index on them), then group the other fields into name/value pairs in an array in the the document. You can then index that array to get your fast searches.

A word of caution on NVP arrays: if you array gets very large (hundreds of attributes), your index size will blow up spectacularly. It's best to try to keep the array size fairly small.

For more information on this design pattern, see Asya's [great writeup](http://askasya.com/post/dynamicattributes).

Comment: I think the best solution is to just see which fields are being querying the most and index those fields, e.g. if it has 12 fields index 3 most used ones.